# How to add # in URL using address.js while using Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, seo, web-crawler, jquery-address

I am developing the ecommerce application in asp.net mvc(4). Where I have called the Specification filters using the Ajax call on Category page. For that I have used two templates. First is to load the Category Layout with header and footer. and Second template will load my products and refresh my Filters blocks.

But when I use the Ajax calls the page url doesn't change. So It also creates the problem for Search engine crawlers. To solve this page I used address.js which puts the # in urls. So Search engines can understand the page.

I have also another problem that when I use the GET method in the ajax call and I click on the back button of browser the all layout disappeared. I can fix this by using the POST method but please advice what is better to use in ajax call.